# is there any other option I can directly stream blob video without using azure media service?

Tags: video-streaming, azure-blob-storage

I have hundreds of video files on azure blob container (block blob) I want it's SAS url as streamable video url so client device don't have to wait until full video download.

I have idea of following options

1. Azure Media Service -
   Issue : creates new container each time for output assets also in media service v3 I don't get any Download path from Streaming locator for media files its just manifest so finally for download I need to use container linked with output asset not sure if this is correct way OR I am missing something here
2. Add header Content-Disposition = inline while generating SAS url from Blob container for media file but I am not sure if that will be actual streaming video or it will first download to temp and play in browser/device directly .
3. I read some where about API that will provide response in chunks of data so you get streaming content but required to multiple calls to that API to get whole video.

which will be best options for streaming video from blob storage ?

Answer (score 2):

There are two strategies when it comes to video delivery :

- Progressive download, where video content is retrieved through “file
  sharing” means where a continuous video file is transferred to the
  client
- Streaming, where the video file is encoded and pre-processed;
  here the file is usually split up un junks and optimized

progressive download, while usually easier to achieve, will not necessarily produce a desired streaming experience as it has no ability to adapt to bandwidth fluctuations, etc through other than extensive buffering, in terms creating extensive wait times.

Simply hosting a video on blob storage for the purpose of providing a streaming-like experience is unlikely to produce the desired experience,while more complex in nature, for a reliable streaming experience, a streaming infrastructure like AMS is imperative.As for the topic about download of an asset in AMS, this is controlled by the streaming policy : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/stream-streaming-policy-concept ,it controls what endpoint access is made available through AMS for an asset.

- If the blob is configured correctly, you can get basic streaming capabilities including forward and reverse seek.  For example, as I type this (might change later), https://aka.ms/FTAISVmultitenant-data uses this ability.  For simple enough use cases, this is fine.  The blob needs appropriate headers (Content-Type needs to be correct in particular; instead of application/content-stream it needs to be for example video/mp4.

This also requires the video file itself to be structured correctly… for example, see [https://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2014/01/streaming-mp4-video-files-in-azure-storage-containers-blob-storage/#:~:text=in%20Windows%20Azure.-,Check%20your%20Videos,-If%20you%E2%80%99ve%20got](https://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2014/01/streaming-mp4-video-files-in-azure-storage-containers-blob-storage/#:%7E:text=in%20Windows%20Azure.-,Check%20your%20Videos,-If%20you%E2%80%99ve%20got) which gets into this.